# Minimum spanning tree algorithm in parallel

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, graph-algorithm

I know some minimum spanning tree algorithms: Boruvka, Prim and Kruskal. Which of them can be implemented in parallel fashion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of these 3 algorithms, only Boruvka algorithm might be easily parallelized.

Quotation from [the description of Boruvka algorithm on algoritmy.net](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/43803/Boruvkas-algorithm):

> A significant advantage of the Borůvka's algorithm is that is might be easily parallelized, because the choice of the cheapest outgoing edge for each component is completely independent of the choices made by other components.